# How can I display images based on the title of the image in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, loops, time, display

I have a folder with images with every letter. Given a sentence, I want to be able to iterate through all the letters in the sentence and display each letter associated image for 3 seconds at a time.  For example, for the sentence "grape", the picture thats titled "g" would display for 3 seconds, then continue to the next letter, etc. Right now, I am displaying the images in the order they are placed in the folder. I am confused about how I can implement the changes I am looking for as I am a beginner in javascript. Thank you in advance, here is what I have now:

```js
            var index = 0;
            change();
            var phrase = "my sentence";
    
            function change() {
                 var pics = document.getElementsByClassName('pictures');
    
                 for(var i = 0; i < pics.length; i++) { 
                     pics[i].style.display = "none"; 
                 }
    
                 for (var j = 0; j < phrase.length; j++) {
                     for (var k = 0; k < pictures.length; k++) {
                         var image = pictures[k].getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
                         var title = image.getAttribute("title");
                         if (phrase[j] == title) {
                             pictures[k].style.display = "block";
                         }
                     }
                 }
    
                 setTimeout(change, 3000);
             }
```

```html
    <section>
        <img class="slides" src="letter_images/a.jpg" style="width:50%">
        <img class="slides" src="letter_images/b.jpg" style="width:50%">
        <img class="slides" src="letter_images/c.jpg" style="width:50%">
        <img class="slides" src="letter_images/d.jpg" style="width:50%">
        <img class="slides" src="letter_images/e.jpg" style="width:50%">
        <img class="slides" src="letter_images/f.jpg" style="width:50%">
        <img class="slides" src="letter_images/g.jpg" style="width:50%">
        <img class="slides" src="letter_images/h.jpg" style="width:50%">
        <img class="slides" src="letter_images/i.jpg" style="width:50%">
        <img class="slides" src="letter_images/j.jpg" style="width:50%">
        <img class="slides" src="letter_images/k.jpg" style="width:50%">
        <img class="slides" src="letter_images/l.jpg" style="width:50%">
        <img class="slides" src="letter_images/m.jpg" style="width:50%">
        <img class="slides" src="letter_images/n.jpg" style="width:50%">
        <img class="slides" src="letter_images/o.jpg" style="width:50%">
        <img class="slides" src="letter_images/p.jpg" style="width:50%">
        <img class="slides" src="letter_images/q.jpg" style="width:50%">
        <img class="slides" src="letter_images/r.jpg" style="width:50%">
        <img class="slides" src="letter_images/s.jpg" style="width:50%">
        <img class="slides" src="letter_images/t.jpg" style="width:50%">
        <img class="slides" src="letter_images/u.jpg" style="width:50%">
        <img class="slides" src="letter_images/v.jpg" style="width:50%">
        <img class="slides" src="letter_images/w.jpg" style="width:50%">
        <img class="slides" src="letter_images/x.jpg" style="width:50%">
        <img class="slides" src="letter_images/y.jpg" style="width:50%">
        <img class="slides" src="letter_images/z.jpg" style="width:50%">
    </section>
```

Comment: If you want to display the images for each letter in `phrase` then you need to check what that letter is.  The `phrase` variable is not used in the `change()` function at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has been pointed out by ATD, `setTimeout` *does not guarantee that the action will be performed at the requested interval*, so I've tried to look for a solution without `setTimeout`.

My idea is to create the full sentence with a loop in javascript and then to use a CSS animation to display one image at a time

```js
const sentence = document.getElementById('sentence');
const mySentence = 'hello world';

const letters = mySentence.split('').filter(letter => /[a-z ]/i.test(letter));

sentence.style.setProperty('--letter-count', letters.length);

letters.forEach(letter => {
  const imgLetter = document.createElement('img');
  letter = letter !== ' ' ? letter : 'Rest';
  imgLetter.src = `letter_images/${letter}.jpg`;
  imgLetter.alt = letter;
  sentence.append(imgLetter);
});
```

```css
#sentence {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* images must have #sentence same size */
#sentence,
#sentence > img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#sentence > img:first-child {
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: calc(3s * var(--letter-count));
  animation-timing-function: steps(var(--letter-count), end);
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

/* -200px = minus the width of #sentence */
@keyframes slide {
  from {margin-left: 0}
  to {margin-left: calc(-200px * var(--letter-count))}
}
```

```html
<section id="sentence"></section>
```

Answer (score 2):

I propose to loop over every letters of the sentence. Each letter will be displayed at index * 3000ms (where index is the index of the letter in the sentence - first letter index = 0, second letter index = 1, ...)

Here is a code example

```js
const imgLetter = document.getElementById('letter');
const sentence = 'hello world';

sentence
  .split('')
  .filter(letter => /[a-z ]/i.test(letter)) // consider only letters and space
  .forEach((letter, index) => {
    setTimeout(_ => {
      letter = letter !== ' ' ? letter : 'Rest'; 
      imgLetter.src = `letter_images/${letter}.jpg`;
      imgLetter.alt = letter;
    }, index * 3000);
  });
```

```html
<section>
    <img class="slides" src="" style="width:50%" id="letter">
</section>
```

Comment: As others have pointed out on other questions, setTimeout does not guarantee that the action will be performed at the requested interval.  You could end up with two images being displayed at the same time?

Comment: This seems to work, but code-only answers are discouraged.  Maybe some explanation on setTimeout?

Comment: thank you! I also have an image I want to display if there is a space in the sentence. The image is titled "Rest". Since your code uses "letter => /[a-z]", would there be a way I can add the check for the space?

Comment: @poromazh I've added a space in the filter (to filter ponctuation for example) and added a line to "rename" letter in "Rest" in case of a space

Comment: @CedricCholley  You may need to add in a final timeout to remove the last letter displayed?

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop through the letters in the `phrase` variable to find each letter, one by one.  From that, you need to find out where it would appear in the alphabet (the `letters` string below).  This should give you a number from 0 to 25.  This should match an index number in your `slides` collection, so you can show the one with the matching index number.

```
    var index = 0;
    var phrase = "my sentence";
    var letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    var tt;

    function change() {
         var pics = document.getElementsByClassName('slides');

         for(var i = 0; i < pics.length; i++) { 
             pics[i].style.display = "none"; 
         }

         let thisLetter = phrase.substr(index, 1);
         if (thisLetter != " ") {
           let thisPos = letters.indexOf(thisLetter);
           pics[thisPos].style.display = "block";
         } else {
           pics[pics.length - 1].style.display = "block";
         }
        index++;
        if (index != phrase.length) {
          tt = setTimeout(change, 3000);
        } else {
          for(var i = 0; i < pics.length; i++) { 
             pics[i].style.display = "none"; 
          }
        }
     }
```

This can't be tested without all of the images being available.  The code does run, but you will need to check it locally to be absolutely sure.

Comment: the `for(...)` loop should be hiding all of the pictures first - only the one that matches in the `thisPos` value should be displayed after that.

Comment: I've just seen that, after the final image has been displayed, it would be left as visible.  So I've updated the code to do a final loop to make sure that they are all hidden.  However, the initial state in your HTML should be `display:none`

Comment: When I try this, all the images are displayed on the page one below another - none of them are changing after 3 seconds. Is this due to the way I have the section of images?

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue.  I've simply copy/pasted your HTML into a blank HTML and run the script - I don't see the images, of course, but, using Inspector in the browser, I can see that the images are being displayed correcly.  I've just updated my code to include the `rest` image on the understanding that it is after the `z` image (otherwise, the alphabets won't tie up).

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach. Load in all the images you're going to need to need and then loop through them all. This way you won't have to load in extra images. If your phrase is long and has duplicate letters and contains most letters, ATD's approach might be better.

```js
let phrase = 'grape',
    index = 0;
    output = document.querySelector('#output');

//Frist we create the phrase with images, all hidden

for (let i = 0; i < phrase.length; i++) {
  output.innerHTML += `<img class="slides" src="letter_images/${phrase[i]}.jpg" style="width:50%" alt="${phrase[i]}">`
}

//Now we show each one, one at a time

var loop = window.setInterval(showNextLetter, 3000 /*3 sec*/);

showNextLetter();

function showNextLetter() {
  let nextLetter = output.children[index],
      oldLetter = document.querySelector('.slides.shown');

  //Make sure it exists
  if (oldLetter) oldLetter.classList.remove('shown');

  nextLetter.classList.add('shown');

  index++;
  
  if (index >= phrase.length) index = 0;
}
```

```css
.slides {
  display: none;
}

.slides.shown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```